# wordpress bootstrap navbar dropdown not working

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, wp-nav-walker

I am using bootstrap nav walker for my WordPress website but the dropdown is not showing up

//bootstrap wp navbar code

```
<div id="desktop-nav" class="header-nav-wrapper">
    <div id="" class="collapse navbar-collapse main-navbar-collapse">
         <?php
                 wp_nav_menu( array(
                 'menu'              => 'header-menu-with-social-icons',
                 'theme_location'    => 'header-menu-with-social-icons',
                 'depth'             => 0,
                 'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                 'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                 'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                 'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                );
        ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

//function.php file code

```
// Register Custom Navigation Walker
require_once('wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php');

/************ Register Menus */
function register_menus() {
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'header-menu' => 'header Menu',
        'header-menu-with-social-icons' => __( 'header-menu-with-social-icons', 'THEMENAME' ),
        'footer-menu' => 'footer Menu'
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_menus' );
```

// bootstrap

```
function foe_james_scripts() {
//    adding bootstrap
    // Add Bootstrap Styles Custom Stylesheet and Bootstrap Scripts
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.4', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'foe_james_a-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    // wp_enqueue_script( 'foe_james_a-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array('jquery'), '20151215', true );

    // wp_enqueue_script( 'foe_james_a-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array('jquery'), '20151215', true );

//    custom js
    wp_register_script('home-page', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/home.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.4', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('home-page');

    // wp_register_script('menu-hover', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/menu-hover.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.4', true );
    // wp_enqueue_script('menu-hover');

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'foe_james_scripts' );
```

Please let me know if you can spot something that I have not from past few hours.

Comment: can you link to your site or a demo with the rendered html/css/js?

Comment: sure. here is the website http://104.193.172.183/~jamesa/ . submenu is under the "with compliment" link

Comment: change the "with compliments" link to `<a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="menu-image-title">With Compliments</span></a>`

Comment: So I changed the href of "With Compliments" to "#" from WP menu section but still not working. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: that's not the only thing you need to change

Comment: Hey man. Sorry to bug you but I did change that. Can you please let me know how can I change the other attributes? its WP and I think I am stuck here. Also, I need access to "with compliments" page too. so is it possible to have link directed ti "with compliments" page and then to sub menu?

Comment: Bootstrap toggles the dropdowns on click, so that dropdown link can't have an `href`. Clicking the link toggles the dropdown. How would you differentiate between a person trying to open/close the menu and follow the link? You should either write your own menu that triggers on `:hover`, or just add another link to the dropdown with the current `href` of "with compliments." I dunno how to tell you to change the attributes on the links, you didn't include any code as to how those links are generated.

Comment: Please have a look at the first snippet code I posted that says
//bootstrap wp navbar code. that's how generated those links. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: did you mean to include something?

Comment: it just has the wp_nav_walker. nothing else I believe

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that is.

Comment: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker
it just helps wordpress sites to implement bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a plugin conflict. The code shown in the question is correct no correction was needed. Just delete the plugin which was conflicting.